# Windows AD unable to reset password from code

Tags: java, windows, active-directory

From code trying to reset AD user password and using the same  password further to login from other services. But AD is not authenticating the user. 
In AD we are updating `userPassword`, `holcimIsRegistered` and `userAccountControl` attributes from our code to reset the password.

When we are manually resetting AD user password from ADSI (right click on user -> go to reset password → reset the password) then AD is authenticating the user with the new password. Neither `userPassword` nor `unicodePwd` attributes are getting updated.

We tried to update `unicodePwd` attribute from ADSI and code also but it's not allowing user to update it's value, from code we have observed

```
[LDAP: error code 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM)]
```

We compared user details before and resetting password from ADSI and observed that few details are getting
updated (`BadLogonCount:0`, `badPasswordTime:0`, `badPwdCount:0`, `lastLogoff:0`, `lastLogon:0`, `logonCount:0`, `Modified`, `modifyTimeStamp`, `msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed`, `PasswordExpired:false`, `PasswordLastSet`, `uSNChanged` and `whenChanged`).

When we tried to modify `usnChanged`, `msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed` from ADSI then observed that these two attributes were not editable from ADSI and from code it was giving `SchemaViolationException`. For `passwordExpired` and `badLogonCount` attributes , we faced `NoSuchAttributeException` while modifying it from code and from ADSI these two attributes were missing.

How else we can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the password, you update the `unicodePwd` attribute. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) tells you about a couple requirements:

1. The new password has to be in a specific format: enclosed in double-quotes and then converted to UTF-16 encoding, and
2. The connection must be encrypted.

[This page](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Example%20-%20Active%20Directory%20Change%20Password%20JNDI) has an example of how to do this in Java, which I've pasted below. It doesn't talk about the encryption, but you can use LDAP over SSL (LDAPS), which you can do by using `LDAPS://` instead of just `LDAP://`. That assumes that the AD server is setup for LDAPS correctly and you don't have a firewall blocking the LDAPS port (636).

```
/**
 * Update User Password in Microsoft Active Directory
 * @param username
 * @param password
 */
public void updateUserPassword(String username, String password)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("updating password...\n");
        String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
        char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray();
        byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < unicodePwd.length; i++)
        {
        pwdArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8);
        pwdArray[i * 2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff);
        }
        System.out.print("encoded password: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < pwdArray.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.print(pwdArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
        mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("UnicodePwd", pwdArray));
        ldapContext.modifyAttributes("cn=" + username + BASE_NAME, mods);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("update password error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You can reset the AD password using the PowerShell.

This Powershell function helps you to reset the Active directory user password from the Domain client computer. The Domain user must member of the Domain Admin to perform the password management from the domain workstation.
While resting the password this function also unlocked the user account.

```
Function Reset-ADUserPassword {
    Param  ([Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0,
            HelpMessage = 'Enter User Name')]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string] $Username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1,
            HelpMessage = 'Enter Password')]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string] $Password
    )
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ActiveDirectoryServerName> -ArgumentList $Username, $Password  -ScriptBlock { param($Username, $Password) import-module activedirectory; Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $Username ; enable-adaccount $Username ; Set-ADAccountPassword $Username -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force); get-aduser -identity $Username -Properties * | select-object UserprincipalName }
    Write-Output "Password Set Successfully for the user: $Username and the password is: $Password ";
    
}
```

Once you run the above function on Powershell use the below command to reset the password.

```
Reset-ADUserPassword -Username abc -Password test@123
```